# React-Bootstrap modal is always open/visible on page

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap's modal to render a modal for my CRUD app when the user clicks on read for an item a modal will pop up with all the info requested. The problem is rendered on first launch of the app and it stays forever. *The modal stays on the bottom of the page* and my Boolean to show/hide the modal, here's how I call it:

```
<Modal.Dialog open={this.state.showServiceModal}>
```

doesn't do anything to help, when I remove the open prop, same result happens: the modal is always visible, and should't models appear on the center of the screen? What gives? The modal appears on the bottom and I want it to appear in the middle and my close modal button doesn't work either, bootstrap's modal is giving me a tough time, how can I fix all of these problems?

Here's my render:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container content">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-6" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <Modal.Dialog open={this.state.showServiceModal}>
        <Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Title>Service</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body>
          <p>
            <span>id:</span> {this.state.currentService.id}
          </p>
          <p>
            <span>description:</span> {this.state.currentService.description}
          </p>
        </Modal.Body>

        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button
            variant="secondary"
            onClick={() => this.setState({ showServiceModal: false })}
          >
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal.Dialog>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `open` prop on `Modal.Dialog` to open and close modals. But react-bootstrap's [documentation has no such API](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) for `Modal.Dialog` as it used to display [*static* modal](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-static).

Use `Modal` component as parent and make use of the `show` prop instead. Also use the `centered` prop to make it vertically centered.

Here is an example:

```
<Modal
    show={this.state.showServiceModal}
    onHide={this.handleClose}
    size="lg"
    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
    centered
 >
    {...}
</Modal>
```

Here is a demo in sandbox:

[image: Edit react-bootstrap]